# How to add dependency to gemfile.lock through gemspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, gemfile.lock

Personnel in relation to `add_runtime_dependency`, `add_dependency` and `add_development_dependency` the "Gem Specification", I'm trying to understand them. How they work and how to differentiate them.

When I used the `add_development_dependency`, I was unable to observe anything different. When I used the `add_dependency` and also the `add_runtime_dependency`, the same effect was observed.

It was added to `gemfile.lock` as the only dependence of my gem, but not a project dependency. And I would like it to be added as a project dependency, because I think add redundant as a unit of my gem, and dependence of the project, adding it to the Gemfile.

What I do not understand is that if I add the jquery as a unit of my gem, but don't add it directly in the application Gemfile, it is not found. I get the following error.

`"could not find file 'jquery'".`

Comment: What does your Gemfile look like?

Comment: @AntarrByrd
My Gemfile does not include the jquery-rails. And it's not even to include. I would like the jquery-rails were included in gemfile.lock through add_runtime_dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You should not gemfile.lock manually. You should include jquery-rails in Gemfile and do bundle install. gemfile.lock is managed by bundler. If you need dependencies only in a given environment you can do something like.

```
group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'bullet'
  gem 'lol_dba'
  gem 'meta_request'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'rbeautify'
  gem 'rsense'
  gem 'rubocop'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'ruby-growl'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'jazz_hands'
end
```

Anything not in a specific group will be included in all environments.

Comment: But add to Gemfile and install it through the bundle command is just what I do not want. I would like the jquery was installed from another gem. Get it?

Comment: @RafaelLaurindo What gem is that? Does it have jquery in it's Gemfile?

Comment: A personal gem. I tried adding the jquery-rails through this my personal gem with the "add_runtime_dependency". Understand?

Comment: Still there is,no valid case I can think of to modify Gemfile.lock

Comment: This means that, unfortunately there as installing a gem through another, there is only how to add it as a dependency in gemfile.lock, right?

Comment: The Gemfile.lock should not be modiried. You can still do this using the Gemfile of either gem

Comment: But after all, what is the purpose of Gemfile of gems?